# FullCalendar IO not showing Database Results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I want to implement a calendar option that can be able to show the  list of events in a specific day. I query my results from the  Database and it comes as a JSON format below :

```
[
    {
    title: "No of Appointments : 48",
    START: "1970-01-01"
    }, 
  {
    title: "No of Appointments : 2",
    START: "2017-06-14"
    }, 
  {
    title: "No of Appointments : 2",
    START: "2017-06-15"
    }, 
  {
    title: "No of Appointments : 1",
    START: "2017-06-20"
    }, 
  {
    title: "No of Appointments : 1",
    START: "2017-06-21"
    }
]
```

And my jquery file is as below :

```
var cal = jQuery.noConflict();
cal(document).ready(function () {
    function get_data() {
        cal.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Reports/get_count_apointments/",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                var appointment_info = data;
                draw_calendar(appointment_info);
            }, error: function (jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    }
    get_data();

    function draw_calendar(appointment_info) {
        cal('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: appointment_info
        });
    }
});
```

However the  following opens the  calendar with no marked event date. 
Hence a blank page with no event on a specific date. 
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your first mistake, please change "START" to lowercase start, then Please check your console and let us know if you are getting any error, , ,

Comment: JS variables are case-sensitive. `start` not `START` for your properties. BTW a more conventional design is as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ instead. Then it can fetch events dynamically just for a specific time period when the user changes the view. At the moment your event list is effectively static and will download all the data into the calendar in one go. Once you build up a lot of historical events this could get slow and inefficient. plus at the moment the calendar will not get drawn until the ajax completes, which might confuse users if they have to wait.

Comment: Thanks it worked :)